# WCF Security options for my scenario

Tags: wcf-security

I need to secure a WCF service and have the following limitations

1. Can use HTTPS
2. Must use basicHttpBinding
3. Must use custom username and password. No windows domain credentials or ASPNET membership is available.

Can you please let me if/how this can be done?

Thanks

Comment: update. This has to be hosted in IIS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout [WCF example: Using of self-hosted service with SSL](http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2006/08/01/897.aspx)